# could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/query/Query

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a project and the below error is showing

Project configuration:

- 5.3.6.Final hibernate-version
- 5.10.3.Final hibernate-search-version
- 6.0.13.Final hibernate-validator-version

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]:
  Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sewerageTaxUtils':
  Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'assignmentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
    Error creating bean with name 'assignmentService': Failed to introspect bean class [org.egov.eis.service.AssignmentService] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/query/Query
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
        ... 36 more
```

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means you have a problem with your classpath at Runtime

Comment: @ControlAltDel, what kind of problems I've been looking on all projects files to catch something but found nothing, what should I look for in specific?

Comment: Check that you don't have duplicate jars of the same dependency but with different versions (your project might depend on some other project which depends other jar you use but with different version)
You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to check the dependencies.